# Javascript promise not working in my case

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have these 2 sets of code. I am trying to retrieve an app_id in the resolver.

Code A:

```
let p1 =  new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(response => {
  //console.log(response.data)
  final_output = {
    "id":response.data
  }
  resolve(final_output)
})
.catch(error => {
  //console.log("Error")
  reject(error)
});
}) 


p1.then(function(final_output){
   return final_output
})
```

and

Code B:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
  final_output = {
    "id":response.data
  }
  resolve(final_output)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("Error")
  reject(error)
});
})
```

I do not understand why Code B would return {"id":1} while Code A would not return {"id:1} to my graphql playground.

Comment: Given all `axios` calls return their own promises, you do not need `new Promise()`

Comment: I've tried removing the new Promise() it didn't work and I have no clue why.

Comment: Both your code samples could be shortened to `return axios.post(url, data).then(({ data }) => ({ id: data }))`

Comment: You have not shown how you're trying to use this code but I suspect _Code A_ should end in `return p1` (assuming these are both some kind of function body)

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by doing this 

`return p1.then(function(final_output){
   return final_output
})`

in code A

Comment: You seriously don't need that last `then`, it is completely redundant. Did you see my short example above?